# Call watsonx.ai prompt in watson assistant

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I created a prompt and satisified with the results. Now I want to connect that prompt i just created to my watson assistant. I googled and knew that it it ls possible by creating custom extensions.  https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/integrate-your-watson-assistant-chatbot-with-watsonxai-for-generative-ai/. But this example doesn't call the a specific prompt.

How can i specifically call the prompt I made through watson assistant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you adapted the configuration to use your prompt and environment?

Comment: isn't the prompt part of your watsonx project

Answer (score 0):

watsonx.ai prompt lab doesn't save the prompts to call them. It saves them so you can work on them later.

If you click on the `</>` it will give you the prompt details you need to fill out when sending your message from watsonx Assistant.

On the same tab there is an (i) information button that will link you to where you get your API key.